# Can Eigen vectors be different with the same normalization proceduce?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I calculated Eigen vectors of two badly-conditioned symmetric matrices of $K$ and $M$ ($M$ is positive definite). I employed two algorithms, the 1st algorithm is `cholesky` and the 2nd one is `qz (generalized Schur decomposition)`.

Eigen vectors $\Phi$ returned by `cholesky` are $M$-orthonormal ($\Phi^T M \Phi = I$). Because $M$ is positive definite, I could easily normalize Eigen vectors of `qz` to be $M$-orthonormal too.

Among my Eigen values $\lambda$, I have 6 Eigen values which are very close to $0$.

When I compare the Eigen vectors of `cholesky` and `qz` side-by-side, I see that all the Eigen vectors are exactly the same, like below: 
[image]
Sometimes they are different with a factor of $-1$ like below: 
[image]
However, for the 6 Eigen values $\lambda$ which are close to zero, the Eigen vectors of `cholesky` and `qz` are different, like below, now my question is that are these different Eigen vectors natural? Shouldn't they be the same?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate, but many people have asked this, so it bears repeating:

> The set of orthonormal eigenvectors spanning a multiply-degenerate eigenspace are not necessarily unique.

This is because a vector space in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension 2 or greater has multiple orthonormal bases.

In addition, even if the vector space has dimension 1, the orthonormal basis is only unique up to phase factors $e^{i\phi}$. Note that $-1=e^{i\pi}$, which explains your sign-flip problem.